# What does the Project Manager star do?

Tags: godot-4

Can't seem to find any reference to [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/project_manager.html),

...but what does the star on the left hand side Godot Engine Project Manager actually do?

[image: Godot Project Manager]

Yes, I also need better names for my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mark a project as *favorite* so the project appears on top of the list.

Comment: Of course it does! :D But doesn't do anything when it's already at the top of the list!